# Setting request Header in Angular post request method globally

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, post, header

I have the following method in an angular service which is working properly

```
 getMyRequests( userId: string){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(CONSTS.MIDDLEWARE_TOKEN)}`);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.MIDDLEWARE_MY_REQUESTS,{ "userId": userId  }, { headers , params: null })
  }
```

However the headers part is set locally in the method, and since it used multiple times in differnt methods within the same service I would like to set it in the service globally
**I tried the following but it doest work**

```
export class MyService {
  
      headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(CONSTS.MIDDLEWARE_TOKEN)}`);
     getMyRequests( userId: string){
        return this.http.post<any>(this.MIDDLEWARE_MY_REQUESTS,{ "userId": userId  }, { this.headers , params: null })
      }
```

I would like to know what is the correct solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you can use the HttpInterceptor interface for this. It provides the  Method

`intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`

which takes your outgoing Request and modifies it the way you want to.

So what you need to do is:

1. Create a new class which implements the HttpInterceptor interface
2. Add the Authorization Header to the request inside the intercept method

Link to Angulars Documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: I can't use this solution because I'm already attaching another header in the current interceptor

Comment: Isn't it possible to set multiple headers in one interceptor? Otherwise have you tried out chaining interceptors?

Comment: You can have as many interceptors as you want..